# dynamic properties with decorators

Tags: python

I would like to create a series of object properties using a loop. Specifically, i want to generate 'secondary' properties by applying a list of functions to existing properties.
my attempt is shown in  a function called `gen_secondary_properties`, shown below. The problem is that all of the properties are equal to one another, and i am not sure why.

```
def gen_secondary_properties(sefl):
    prop_dict = {
        's' : self.s,
        'y' : self.y,
        'z' : self.z,
        }
    func_dict = {
        'real': npy.real,
        'imag': npy.imag,
        }
    for prop_key in prop_dict:
        for func_key in func_dict:
            fget = lambda self: func_dict[func_key](prop_dict[prop_key])
            setattr(self.__class__,'%s_%s'%(prop_key, func_key),\
                property(fget))
```

what DOES work is a function which creates a single property at a time, and then call this function from the loop.

```
def __add_secondary_property(self, func , prop_name):
    fget = lambda self: func(self.__getattribute__(prop_name))
    setattr(self.__class__,'%s_%s'%(prop_name,func.__name__),\
        property(fget))


for prop_name in ['s','z']:
    for func in [npy.real, npy.imag]:
        self.__add_secondary_property(func, prop_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you call `setattr()` on `self.__class__`: `__class__` is shared by all instances. If you modify it, you modify it for everyone. Try `setattr(self, ...)`

Alternatively, change the code of `fget` to look up the value in the instance when it is called (i.e. later when someone tried to read the property) instead of when the getter is defined. What you do in the code above is copy the current value of `self.s` into a shared getter (shared by all instances).

Comment: using setattr(self,..) returns a property type instead of actually creating a property for the parent object